# document.writeln doesn't concatenate === comparison correctly

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

Here's a plunk that demonstrates my question: http://plnkr.co/edit/322WB4jyCJberABbb0P0

I'm doing some testing for a different issue and I came across some unexpected behavior.

```
var A = function() {}
A.prototype = {
  constructor: A,
  x: 10
};

var a = new A();

document.writeln("a.x is " + a.x + "<br>");
document.writeln("a.constructor === A is " + a.constructor === A + "<br>");
var result = a.constructor === A;
document.writeln("a.constructor === A is " + result + "<br>");
```

The second writeln doesn't concatenate the strings with the value and it writes "false".  The third writeln concatenates and writes as expected.

This isn't really something I'd do outside of testing, but I'd like to understand why the second writeln behaves this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `===` has a lower precedence than `+` - otherwise you wouldn't be able to write simple equations like `a + b === c + d`!

So just use parentheses around `(a.constructor === A)` and all will be well.

Comment: Ah, so the way it is written now is the same as document.writeln(("a.constructor === A is " + a.constructor) === (A + "<br>")); which would return false.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Jeff I suggest not using `document.writeln`, append it to the DOM is better practice.

Comment: @RUJordan, I aggree with what you're saying.  I'm only using document.writeln for some quick testing as an alternative to alert().  I normally use console.log, but I was too lazy to open the console this time.  Funny thing is that actually would have been faster because of this question.  Upside is now I have some more good information.